# How to configure Jenkins login with google apps

Tags: authentication, jenkins, google-apps, google-account

I had installed Jenkins in Ubuntu machine and making build successfully. I want to have authentication with help of Google apps. I feel it would be better, I searched the plugin respective to this, but i can't find it. whether this can be attained by means of plugin or otherways? Please do let me know the ways to do. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve Single Sign On with Google Apps using the [OpenID Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/OpenID+plugin#OpenIDplugin-WorkingwithGoogleApps). It's very easy to set up, you basically install the plugin, select "Google Apps SSO (with OpenID)" and enter your domain. Note that users *will* have to have a google apps account to login after that.

Tip: you might consider using it in combination with the [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin)

Comment: Hi please i am in need that i had wrongly configured my security settings and now i am unable to access please let me know how to enable access again

Comment: To reset your security, disable it: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

Comment: Does this still work with Google forcing migration to Oauth2?

Comment: @Gus not as far as I can see. I am exploring alternatives as well

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to use the new Google OAuth2 authentication service on Jenkins. If someone has some information, please be kind and share ;)

Comment: gasp, just adopted Google Apps for Work to discover that they deprecated OpenID and XMPP. Don't be evil WHAT?

Answer (score 12):

Now that Google deprecated support for OpenID, you can use [Google Login Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Login+Plugin) which works well with Google Apps.

Answer (score 9):

In Jenkins by default **user authentication is not enabled** but we can establish the user authentication from the **Global Security** section. We have to create users for team members and it maintains all user in its own database. But we can also configure Jenkins with **Google OAuth**. So, if you are leveraging Google services and already have users on it. The users can login to Jenkins and perform their task.

To implement Google OAuth we'll recommend `jenkinsci/google-login-plugin` (https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-login-plugin) this is a **Jenkins plugin** which lets you **login to Jenkins with your Google account**. Also allows you to restrict access to accounts in a given Google Apps domain.

I am assuming that we have already installed Jenkins server and have admin right to make changes in it. The whole configuration is divided into three easy steps.

**1. Get Google OAuth Credentials**

To use this plugin, you must obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials from the `Google Developers Console` (https://console.developers.google.com). These don't need to belong to a special account, or even one associated with the domain you want to restrict logins to.

Instructions to create the Client ID and Secret:

- Login to the Google Developers Console
- Create a new project, in the pop-up window specify your project
  name it can be any name which is more meaning full to you, eg:
  `Jenkins OAuth`. In this project we will generate authantication
  credentials to enable OAuth API.
- On the left sidebar under APIs & Services (API Manager) ->
  Credentials, Create credentials, OAuth client ID (It will genrate API
  credentials and these credentails are required to configure in
  Jenkins in last step).
- As we are going to integrate this in Jenkins and it is a web
  service, the application type should be **"Web Application"**
- Register Jenkins URI from where we allowed to access the Google
  APIs. We have to provide Jenkins server detail. You can replace your
  **JENKINS_ROOT_URL** = `http:jenkins.mydomain.com` with your own Jenkins URI. This will be the landing page of your Jenkins server.
  Once you hit this page it will be redirected to google for the
  authentication.
- The authorized redirect URIs is required to redirect you after
  successful login. It is the combination of your Jenkins landing page
  and a suffix string to validate you are a logged in user. As we want
  to land user to Jenkins dashboard, so it has the same URI which we
  mentioned in the previous step and don’t forget to include
  `securityRealm/finishLogin` at the end. So the authorized redirect
  URLs should result like this
  `${JENKINS_ROOT_URL}/securityRealm/finishLogin`.

  **eg:** `http://jenkins.mydoamin.com/securityRealm/finishLogin`
- Copy and save **Client ID and Client Secret**, these credential
  will be used to enable Google APIs in Jenkins (Security Realm
  Configuration).

**2. Install Google Login Plugin**

In Jenkins there is no mechanism to configure OAuth but there are many plugins are available and we are using **Google Login plugin**. We can easily install this plugin from `Manage Jenkins` –> `Manage Plugins` –> `Available` and search for “Google Login”. Select the plugin. There is no need to restart to install this plugin. This plugin allows for the register Google OAuth and performs authentication.

**3. Configure Jenkins**

In this step, we will setup Google security credentials in installed plugin. Navigate to `Manage Jenkins` –> `Configure Global Security` and select `Login with Google` under **Security Realm** paste credentials (Client ID and secret) generated in the first step. In the last field do not forget to enter your domain name it allows you to restrict access to given domain name.

Immediately after saving changes Jenkins will allow access to all users in your domain. Now, try to login into your Jenkins it will redirect you to Google Authentication page. If everything is set up properly you will be logged in but just in case you’re still facing any problem go back and check each step. The logged in user can do anything and if you want to restrict users you can implement **Role Strategy Plugin** (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) security.

Comment: A warning if you are already using the Role Strategy Plugin before you switch to Google auth: I think that was the reason I was initially locked out of Jenkins after making the switch from LDAP auth to Google auth. I believe the Role Strategy Plugin saw our Google accounts as non-configured users and gave them no rights. I was able to fix it by using my still-logged-in-with-LDAP browser session to add the Google account to the Role Strategy Plugin settings.

Answer (score 0):

I used a command line browser called elinks to sign in to their html mail server http://m.gmail.com.
Use shift in Elinks to copy and paste.

http://minimallinux.blogspot.com/2012/07/centos-6rhel-install-elinks-text-browser.html

I switched a text message script from one jenkins box to another and had to do this to get Google to let me use that IP.